# eslint: how to allow aligning of method calls

Tags: javascript, eslint

If I have code like this:

```
something.method1()
         .method2()
         .method3()
```

How do I allow this style of indent? A simple offset count does not work since the alignment is based on the length of the variable name.

Comment: Did you look at this: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/newline-per-chained-call ?

Comment: Yes, that does not make code like I entered above pass. I still get an error about the indent not being 8 as expected.